# How to check if a given virtual address points to a given exported function from a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I'm inspecting the process memory of an executable and 
I want to see if a given virtual address `addr` points inside the code segment of a given exported function `func` from a DLL.

**Question 1:** Is it possible to determine if a virtual address is pointing to the code of a given function, without any debugging symbols?

**Assumption:** The code of `func` is contiguous. *Comments below state that this assumption is wrong*

**Idea:** Check if `addr` lies between start and end addresses of `func`.

**Implementation:** The [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is used to retrieve the starting address (`start_func`) of `func`. If there would be a function which can either retrieve the ending address (`end_func`) of `func` or its size (`size_func = end_func - start_func`) and if the previous assumption would hold, then one could solve **Question 1** using the following condition:

```
(start_func <= addr) && (addr <= end_func)
```

**Question 2:** Is it possible to determine if a virtual address is pointing to the code of a given function, with debugging symbols? How?

Comment: what's purpose of this?

Comment: No there isn't. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: You mean code size?? That info is available using some tool like `nm` (don't know actually for PE format) and inspecting the executable file. As @Matt and @MarkRansom mentioned that sounds like a XY-problem!

Comment: I want to know whether an address points inside the code of a certain function

Comment: @Benny _'whether an address points inside the code'_ You don't want to tell us you want to address a `goto` label there, don't you?!?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No I don't want that.

Comment: @Benny Then elaborate (edit your question) please! It's absolutely unclear what you're asking for, and which use case could be properly applied for such feature. 1st: **Why** do you need this? 2nd: Do you need this for runtime operations or offline statistics, etc.??

Comment: 'size of a function' - including other function/s that may/may not be called?  'ending address' - what if it has more than one?

Comment: '(start_func <= addr) && (addr <= end_func)' - that's not gonna work except in trivial cases where nothing else gets called.

Comment: @MartinJames any other suggestions are very welcome

Comment: @Benny - see Matt comment - what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MartinJames I can't explain it clearer than it is now. I really don't get what you want me to tell you. It is a very simple problem.

Comment: When people ask what you're trying to do, they mean "What are you going to do after the `if` statement?" What decision are you going to make based on this information? Note that there is no requirement that all the code for a function be contiguous, so the question as posed is not answerable.

Comment: @Benny, why do you need to know if an address is within a function body?

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks, I didn't know that. This is the single useful comment I got so far.

Comment: You've never seen a function call another one declared, and probably located, earlier?  IIRC, it's quite common.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm didn't understand what you just wrote. What is IIRC?

Comment: @Benny, If I Recall Correctly.

Comment: Sorry, never mind.  I cannot make sense of whatever it is you are trying to do, so I cannot help with your problem.  I'm going to the pub now.  I'll have an extra pint in memory of your question.

Comment: @Benny, so, finally, can we know what are you going to do after the if statement?

Comment: @Jefffrey If `addr` is a return address, I want to know in which function it will be returning to. That's it, nothing spectacular

Comment: @Benny, and what are you going to do with that information?

Comment: @Jefffrey display it to the end-user of my process inspection tool

Comment: Then use the [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dll has the program database (PDB) deployed with it, you can get this information via dbghelp.dll.

There is no reliable way to get this information without debug information. However, you can get some idea by enumerating all the exports from a DLL, which would at least give you the address of any routine that follows in memory. That can be done with imagehlp.dll.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the beginning of a function with `GetProcAddress` but there is no analogous function call that tells you where it ends.

If you have the map file for the program then you can obtain the information you need. However, it would be unusual for you to have the map file unless you are building the DLL.

Other than that, you could disassemble the code, starting at the address returned by `GetProcAddress`. However, that's pretty hard to do in a robust way. You could probably get reasonably close without too much effort, but you'll likely never be 100% accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am building the DLL and I do have the PDB for it.

Comment: Then you are good to go! But it's a shame you did not tell us that so we could have used less time. And in any case, it might be easier with the map file than the pdb.

Comment: :) yes I am. However, I'm absolutely astonished at how many down-votes this simple question got.

Comment: I'm not surprised. It's a poor question. You asked if an address was inside the code segment. Then you restated that as how to find the length of a function. It's very confused.